# ajax image as response in php

Tags: php, ajax, image, response

I want to display an image as a response to an ajax call using php.. Does anybody have the complete code for this?? Please help me out..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't have the complete code to this, and if I did, I wouldn't give it to you.

You need to start off by creating an image using [PHP's various image generation functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php). To make it dynamic you could send it [various parameters which are encoded in the url](http://javascript.about.com/library/blqs.htm?rd=1) and can be fetched using the [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) superglobal in php.

You would then set the `src` of an existing image placeholder element to the location of your dynamic image, then voila! Instant dynamic image.

Comment: If the asker has difficulties with any of the above, then they probably shouldn't be attempting whatever they are doing and try something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) + [JSON](http://www.json.org/) combination. You can convert php array into JSON format using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

**index.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>

<a href='car.php' class='ajax'>Car Image</a>
<a href='bike.php' class='ajax'>Bike Image</a>

<div id="title">Title comes here</div>
<div id="image">Image comes here</div>
```

**car.php:**

```
<?php
$jsonArray['title'] = "Car";
$jsonArray['image'] = "<img src='images/car.jpeg'>";
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
?>
```

**bike.php:**

```
<?php
$jsonArray['title'] = "Bike";
$jsonArray['image'] = "<img src='images/bike.jpeg'>";
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
?>
```

**ajax.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('.ajax').click(function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      jQuery.getJSON(this.href, function(snippets) {
          for(var id in snippets) {
              jQuery('#' + id).html(snippets[id]);
          }
      });
  });

});
```